# increment a variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made this script, but there is a problem.

When i click `addbutton` the variable on console log recieve the update (1, 2 ,3 ,4) for every click.

But `var fieldHTML` remains 1 forever, why?

```
var a = 1;

$(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked

a++;

console.log(a);


});

var fieldHTML = a;
```

Comment: Because `a` is pointing to a new value, but `fieldHTML` is still pointing to old one.

Comment: [_It's always pass by value(even when that value is a reference...)_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: ^ except objects and arrays which pass by reference.

Comment: Objects and arrays are still pass by value, the difference is that the value you have in the first place is a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `var fieldHTML = a;` copies the value of `a` to `fieldHTML`.

It doesn't create a reference.

Changing the value of `a` (after you've set the value of `fieldHTML`) won't change the value of `fieldHTML`.

Comment: I did not understand, you could do a little example?

Comment: @MaurizioBenini — An example of what? I'm just describing what the example you provided does.

Comment: there is a way to update fieldHTML with the increment value?

Comment: Only by updating it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply an id or class to the selector, wrap it into document ready, and also pass the new value of "a" to a function that can then manipulate the fieldHTML value.  Check out the snippet note that I used alerts to demonstrate the increasing count rather thanconsole.log - simply because its in the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var a = 1;
      $('#addButton').click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
       a++;
       alert("a = " + a);
       update_fieldHTML(a);
      });
  })

function update_fieldHTML(value){
var fieldHTML = value;
  alert("fieldHTML =" + fieldHTML);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addButton">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var addButton = $("#btn");
var viewButton = $("#btn-2");
var setButton = $("#btn-3");
var a = 1;
var fieldHTML = a; // on load, addign a value to fieldHTML variable  |  fieldHTML = 1

$(addButton).click(function() { //Inc by 1
  a++;
  console.log('a : '+a);
});

$(viewButton).click(function() {  //Show fieldHTML value in console
  console.log('fieldHTML : '+fieldHTML);
});

$(setButton).click(function() { // reassign a value to the fieldHTML variable  | on click event
  fieldHTML = a;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='btn'>Inc a</button>
<button id='btn-3'>Set fieldHTML</button>
<button id='btn-2'>View fieldHTML</button>
```

Comment: The way you wrote it, this code `var fieldHTML = a;` was executed on the window load event. After you increment `a` value you have to **reassign** its value to `fieldHTML` somehow.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var addButton = $("#btn");
var viewButton = $("#btn-2");
var a = 1;
var fieldHTML = a;

$(addButton).click(function() { 
  fieldHTML = increment();
  alert('a : ' + a);
});

$(viewButton).click(function() {
  alert('fieldHTML : '+fieldHTML);
});

function increment(){
   return ++a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='btn'>Inc a</button>
<button id='btn-2'>View fieldHTML</button>
```